# Laravel 5 Session working in Postman not working if called from browser

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

After login I use session to set the user details. If i use postman i can get the session details. If i try logging from my browser its showing null

Here is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Session;

class UserController extends Controller {

  public function login(){
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $requestArray = array();
    foreach($request as $key => $value){
      $requestArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    $user = User::login($requestArray);
    Session::put("activeuser", $user);
    Session::save();
    return json_encode(array('result'=>Session::get("activeuser")));

  }
```

Controller to fetch session details

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Session;


class ThisSessionController extends Controller {

  public function getdetails($key)
  {

        return json_encode(array($key => Session::get($key)));

  }

}
```

config/session.php

```
        'driver' =>  'file',
```

**Edit 1**
As a point of information, i use laravel to make only api calls. So my domain will be api.mydomain.com/sessiondetails/activeuser

Is this the problem?

**Edit 2**

[image]

The first object is the ajax call to the session get url and second object is the return value after login success.

Two tokens were totally different.

**Edit - 3**

I have updated laravel with jwt and it is throwing JWT::Factory is not available. below is my updated code.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager as JWT;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class UserController extends Controller {

  public function login(Request $request){

   $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
   $user = User::login($requestArray);
   if($user){

     $payload = JWTFactory::make($credentials);
     $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
   }


    return json_encode(array('result'=>$token));

  }
```

**Edit - 4**

I changed the code inside login function and i get result as

```
{"token":{}}
```

UserController@login code

```
$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob']; 
$payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($customClaims);
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

**EDIT 5**

My final working code that could generate the token in laravel is

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

   try {
        $user = User::login($credentials);
        if(!$user)
          throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);

   } catch (Exception $e) {
       return response()->json(['error' => false]);
   }

   $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

   return response()->json(compact('token'));  

  }
```

Comment: If i use Session::get in the same page its returning. I dont get it if i make a call to another url

Comment: did you check for csrf_token ?

Comment: both are different. I wil post the pic

Comment: in 2nd object, where you see Array[1], try this print_r(your_session_obj, true).

Comment: Its an api call. Its from the same page where i set the session, userController@login ..... The data is populating. On study, i identify, everytime i make an api call a new session is generated. How to overcome that.

Comment: Do not put the password in the payload. The code in edit 3 will expose the password in plain text!! That is a huge security problem!

Comment: Hi.can you confirm me on edit  5 is that method ok?@jfadich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Sessions use a cookie to keep track of the session. You visit the page mydomain.com and the browser sends cookies for that domain, but when the javascript makes requests to api.mydomain.com it doesn't include cookies because it's a cross domain request so the session can't be tracked.

Token authentication is stateless meaning there is no session to save to or retrieve from. All the information needed for the request must be included in the request. So you get the user information from the token.

On your login page you post the credentials and return a token. Your frontend will then attach the token to every subsequent request.

This example assumes you use [JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), but the concept would work with any token service.

```
  public function login(Request $request){

    // This is all unnecessary. You're in Laravel, take advantage of the services Laravel provides. Use [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input) instead.
    //$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    //$request = json_decode($postdata);
    //$requestArray = array();
    //foreach($request as $key => $value){
    //  $requestArray[$key] = $value;
    //}

    // change email to username depending on what you use to authenticate
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    $user = User::login($requestArray);
    if($user){
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser(User::where('username', $credentials['username'])->first());
    } else {
        return response()->json(array('error' => 'invalid credentials')))

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));

  }
```

Once you have a token you can use the JWT middleware `jwt.auth` to protect any route. To get the user info from the token use `JWTAuth::toUser()`

```
public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return JWTAuth::toUser()->toJson();
}
```

Instead of making requests to get session data from the server, you should store that information on the client side.

Comment: Exactly, Session stores on server. You just send User Credentials to API, verify that user is valid then return User information.

Comment: I got the issue. I dont use jwtauth. but i can take the token to my angularjs application. Now how do i retrieve the data based on that token.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Well that would depend on how you make the token. Look at the documentation for the package you use to find out how to get info from a token.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene because when you make a request directly to api.mydomain.com with postman it will include the cookies and the session will work. It is when you request the api with ajax cross domain that the cookies are not sent and breaks sessions.

Comment: @jfadich, can you help me for  mins to understand how its done. I installed jwt and no idea where should i write the code and get it with angularjs. I know there is a chat room in stack overflow. Not sure how to activate it. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99099/angularjs-laravel-5-jwt-integrration.

Comment: @jfadich. I updated the code and it says jwt::factory is missing. can you look into my edit-3 coding

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene You don't need to use jwt::factory at all. You can just use JWTAuth::fromUser() since you're validating the credentials elsewhere. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: didnt work.  It said undefined variable user. But another code on my crawl gives blank object. Its in edit-4

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene did you do any debugging on your own before asking again here? That error should not happen on the code on this page. The user variable is defined. Again you don't need to use the factory. They way you have it now the password will be exposed in plain text!!

Comment: Got the token generated if login fails. Looking for guidance to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

## first _  you must login user in web route not api

## second _ if your session work in normal request but not in your app  you can use cors middleware for sending cross platform requests like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function()
{

    Route::post('/auth/register',[UserApiController::class, 'register'] );
    Route::post('/auth/login',[UserApiController::class, 'login'] );
    Route::post('/auth/verify',[UserApiController::class, 'verify'] );

});
```

- in  laravel by default you cant use cors middleware but you can install the npm package from here https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors